# Is this functor exact?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence, functors

I would like to pose a question which is, from my point of view, surprisingly elementary, difficult and interesting at the same time. I hope that somebody could enlighten me.

Let $k$ be a field and $A$ be a $k$-algebra which is a domain, with fraction field $K$. Let $L_1, \dots L_d$ be a finite number of elements of $K$. Let $A[L] \subseteq K$ be the $A-$algebra generated by the elements $L_1, \dots , L_d$, inside $K$.

Consider the localisation functor $(-)^*$, from the category of $A$-modules to the category of $K$ modules, sending $M$ to $M^*= (A \setminus \{0 \})^{-1} M$.  We have a canonical map of $A$-modules $\iota : M \longrightarrow M^*$.

Then, consider the functor $(-)[L]$, from the category of $A$-modules to the category of $A[L]$-modules, sending $M$ to the $A[L]$-module generated by $\iota(M)$, inside $M^*$.

The question is: is the functor $(-)[L]$ exact (or left exact or right exact)? If not, is it exact (or left exact or right exact) under some condition? Or else, can you find a condition on an exact sequence of $A$-modules $0 \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow  N \longrightarrow  K \longrightarrow  0$ (resp.  $0 \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow  N \longrightarrow  K $) such that applying $(-)[L]$ preserves the exacteness of this sequence.

Of course, the problem is easy if $L_i= \frac{1}{a_i}$ for some $a_i \in A$, for any $i$, but if this is not the case, then in my opinion the problem becomes quite hard. Also, if I'm not wrong, the functor $(-)[L]$ should preserve injections and surjections. But exactness in the middle of a sequence is a mess. I would be glad to have some help!

Comment: How does your functor differ from just extension of scalars $A \to A[L]$?

Comment: Good question, if $M$ if flat over $A$, there is no difference. In general, there is a surjective morphism $A[L] \otimes_A M \longrightarrow M[L]$, but I'm not sure it is an isomorphism in general.

Comment: OK, I think I see the difference: in general, given ring maps $A \to B \to C$, you can compare $- \otimes_A B$ with $(- \otimes_A C)_B$ (first extend scalars to $C$, then restrict scalars to $B$), and these will be different e.g. if there is an $A$-module $M$ with $M \otimes_A B \ne 0$ but $M \otimes_A C = 0$ (in your case, you could take $M = A/(f)$, for some $f \in A$ which does not become a unit in $A[L]$)

Comment: Anyways, extension of scalars is right exact, and restriction of scalars (being right adjoint to extension) is left exact. Not sure what can be said about exactness of the composite in general though